# Spacing when transitioning tile size

Tags: tile, grout, ceramic-tile

I'm putting down my first ceramic tile floor. I need to transition from 18 inch to 6 inch tile for part of my design.

I've been installing the 18 inch tile with 1/4 inch spacing for looks. I'd like to keep the same 1/4 inch of grout every third tile, basically making a a 3x3 set of these 6 inch tile act like one of the 18x18.

How do I do that? I'm sure it's just a matter of finding the right spacing.

Edit: true sizes at 5 13/16th and 17 13/16th.

Comment: Can you confirm that your tiles are 18" actual and 6" actual? If you were a little undersized on the 6" (and all this depends on the actual tile -- rectified or not...), you could probably get away with a very thin grout line inside your 3x3s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, this might work... you'd line up the outsides of the 3x3 grid with your 18" tile. You'd have about a 1/8" grout line inside the 3x3 grid. You'd maintain the 1/4" grout line around the 3x3.

Don't take my word for it, though: lay it out on the ground and see what you (and any other people with veto power that have to live with it) think.

Oh, and depending on the grout you choose, you might have to switch from sanded to unsanded. Just check the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I played with the maths on it and it looks like 3/16 will line up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late now but you should have thought before hand and did a mock lay out at minimum. If you didn't calculate this out first you will find that once you reach the opposite wall the tile may be to big or not big enough. Leaving you with more grout, less grout or having to cut tile.
The same goes if you tiled the edges and are working inward to the center or center outward. 
Not being a jerk here I speak from professional experience you have a hard task ahead good luck